# "Invalid bytes error" on migration of PascalLigo contract

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo, truffle

I am trying to write tests for my contract, which stores an user as follows:

```
    type userData is record [
    addressSet : set(bytes);
    storedAmount : tez;
    ]
```

My storage is a big_map as follows:

```
type storage is big_map (string, userData);
```

When I am trying to run the contract, it compiles, but fails on the compilation with

`Error: while migrating Vault: [0] Invalid bytes: 0,116,0,122,0,49,0,104,0,115,0,88,0,112,0,107,0,101,0,118,0,87,0,74,0,87,0,107,0,101,0,57,0,116,0,105,0,107,0,111,0,103,0,74,0,102,0,86,0,50,0,116,0,68,0,56,0,100,0,119,0,120,0,80,0,82,0,101,0,70,0,85,...`

This if the initial storage json I am providing for the migration:

```
initial: {
    addressSet:
    [
        "tz1hsXpkevWJWke9tikogJfV2tD8dwxPReFU",
        "tz1hsXpkevWJWke9tikogJfV2tD8dwxPReFK"
    ],
    storedAmount:1000,
},
```

My migration script for truffle looks like this:

```
const Vault = artifacts.require("Vault");
const {MichelsonMap} = require("@taquito/taquito");
const acc = require ("../scripts/sandbox/accounts");

function packString(str) {
    var bytes = [];
    for(var i = 0, n = str.length; i < n; i++) {
        var char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes.push(char >>> 8, char & 0xFF);
    }
    return bytes;
}

module.exports = async (deployer, _network, accounts) => {
    const identifier = acc.initial.identifier;
    const addressSetBytes = [];
    // Access the "initial" json stated above to get the string addresses
    const address1Bytes = packString(acc.initial.addressSet[0]);
    const address2Bytes = packString(acc.initial.addressSet[1]);
    addressSetBytes.push(address1Bytes);
    addressSetBytes.push(address2Bytes);
        const userData =
        {
            addressSet: addressSetBytes,
            storedAmount: acc.initial.storedAmount,
        };
        const testUser = "Mike";
    const storage = new MichelsonMap();
    storage.set(testUser, userData);
    deployer.deploy(Vault, storage);
};
```

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong and why the byte array I am providing should be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It worked as soon as I provided the HEX of the addressSet[] values.
Maybe someone can explain why this is the case. I stumbled upon this solution after trying out for hours by accident.